CERN-OHL-P 2.0: include notices in proprietary project
CERN-OHL-P 2.0 requires to keep notices when modifying Covered Source:

3.3 You may Convey modified Covered Source (with the effect that You shall
also become a Licensor) provided that You:
a) retain Notices as required in subsection 3.2; and
b) add a Notice to the modified Covered Source stating that You have
modified it, with the date and brief description of how You have
modified it.

How to keep notices if the modification is part of the proprietary project?

The license quite clearly states that you must not delete Notices. Can you elaborate how you think that might be a problem in a proprietary project?

@BartvanIngenSchenau Notices are usually located in file (e.g. CHANGES.txt) that is located in the source repository. If the project is proprietary, there is nowhere to place CHANGES.txt with notices

Why would a proprietary project not have a source repository (which can be as simple as a folder structure on disk)? The other Sources need to be stored somewhere as well.

Do you mean that even if project is not published anywhere but if notices are stored on local drive in the directory of proprietary project, it counts as keeping notices?

Yes, that is correct. But keep clause 4 in mind al well, which requires that recipients of the Product can access the Notices as well (which can be satisfied by providing a print-out of the Notices along with the Product).

@BartvanIngenSchenau If proprietary project includes material licensed under CERN-OHL-P (for example, one of many PCBs in the project), can notices relate only for this PCB (not to full project), and can it be noted on print-out?

It would be good to make it clear the Notices refer only to a part of the Product (which would probably count as an additional Notice), but you don't need to provide information on the rest of the Product. And yes, those can be noted on a print-out.

I think the answer(s) to question "Apache License 2.0 - How to state changes when distributing a derivative software in closed-source way" applies here too.
Here's the accepted answer to that question:

That clause of the Apache license does not require you to openly
publish the modified sources, so you can prove to the public that you
are following the license terms.
The worst case that I can see happening is that there are other
indications that you are violating the license, a copyright holder
takes you to court and demands that you prove in court how you are
complying with that clause.
On the other hand, I would recommend that you add the notice to the
modified files anyway, just in case someone later on decides to
publish the sources of that modified version of A anyway.
Additionally, I would recommend that where you mention that you are
using A, that you include a mention that it is a modified version of
A.

